# Direct Geodesic with Point 2 Azimuth

Tags: spherical-geometry, geodesic

I am trying to find a way to calculate the direct problem on the WGS-84 ellipsoid but instead of using the initial Azimuth (e.g. lat1, lon1, distance, fwd azi), I want to compute it with the reverse Azimuth (e.g. lat1, lon1, distance, point2-reverse-azimuth).

Are there any tools/libraries out there to do that?

My purpose is to find the tangential latitudes and longitudes to a circle of radius X from any given point -- to calculate an accurate lat/long bounding box that contains all points within X distance.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. I understand the first part of your question (and don't know the solution). The second part seems relatively trivial: covert a difference in latitude distance into a difference in latitude angle. I don't understand the connection between parts one and two, however. Can you **[edit]** to clarify?

Comment: The questioner's problem is to find not only the latitude extent of the bounding box (relatively simple, as you note), but also the longitude extent (a more interesting problem); see below for my answer.

Comment: OK, thanks to cffk, i understood, and slightly edited, your Q.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to solve the ellipsoidal triangle where

φ<sub>1</sub>, α<sub>2</sub>, *s*<sub>12</sub>

are given.  (See Figure 1 of the Wikipedia article, [Geodesics on an
ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid), for the notation.)  In your case, we have
α<sub>2</sub> = ±½π because of the requirement of
tangency.  This is Problem 7 in §10 of my paper

[Geodesics on an ellipsoid of revolution](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.1215) (Feb. 2011)

The solution entails assuming a value of α<sub>1</sub> (perhaps by
solving an equivalent spherical problem), solving the ellipsoidal
triangle given

φ<sub>1</sub>, α<sub>1</sub>, α<sub>2</sub>

(Problem 2), determining the resulting *s*<sub>12</sub>, and correcting
α<sub>1</sub> using Newton's method.  The derivative needed for
Newton's method, d*s*<sub>12</sub>/dα<sub>1</sub> is given by
Eq. (79).  Problem 2 is trivial to solve: convert to the auxiliary
sphere (β<sub>1</sub>, α<sub>1</sub>, α<sub>2</sub>),
determine σ<sub>12</sub> using some subset of Eqs. (9) thru (18),
and find *s*<sub>12</sub> by using the routine Geodesic::ArcDirect in my
library [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sf.net).  (Here β is the parametric latitude and
σ is the arc distance on the auxiliary sphere.)

Assuming that your initial guess is sufficiently good, this will
converge to the desired solution quadratically (the number of correct
digits in α<sub>1</sub> will double on each iteration).

Comment: You are a computational geodesist of the highest order! I wish you'd participate even more often.

Comment: Not only that, but very generous: I simultaneously emailed my question and received a response within hours.  Thank you again!